# Implicit conversion error only when running query via an application not through Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, silverlight

I am executing a stored procedure on the same SQL Server 2012 database with the same user in two ways: (1) through a Silverlight application and (2) through SQL Server Management Studio.

I am getting `"Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to timestamp is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query"` when I run it through the Silverlight app but not via SSMS. I have run the Profiler to grab the SQL, to ensure that I am running the same query in SSMS, so that's not the issue.

Here is the SQL:

`exec "SP_FOO" @Inserted='2014-05-14 15:29:59.700',@ChangedBy=N'CORP1\Badger.Spot',@ValidationInfo=NULL,@CODE=N'NuVal',@APP_SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP=NULL,@APP_SYSTEM_UPDATED='2014-05-14 15:29:59.700',@APP_SYSTEM_UPDATED_UPDATE=1,@APP_SYSTEM_CHANGEDBY=N'CORP1\Badger.Spot',@APP_SYSTEM_CHANGEDBY_UPDATE=1,@MY_INT=1900,@MY_INT_UPDATE=1`

The DB user I am using in both instances has a language of "English".  I previously had been getting the same error in SSMS when the user had a language of "British English" but on changing it to "English" this stopped.

I have restarted the machine (the DB is on the local machine). The PC's regional setting is "English (UK)".

I suspect that this is something to do with a regional setting as changing the language fixed the issue in SSMS but this might not be the case.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Update: I can't see how the SP itself can be the issue as it runs from SSMS. However here it is:

```
ALTER PROC [SP_FOO]     
    @Inserted DATETIME
    , @ChangedBy NVARCHAR(256)
    , @ValidationInfo NVARCHAR(4000)
    , @CODE VARCHAR(20)
    , @APP_SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP
    , @APP_SYSTEM_UPDATED DATETIME
    , @APP_SYSTEM_UPDATED_UPDATE bit
    , @APP_SYSTEM_CHANGEDBY NVARCHAR(50)
    , @APP_SYSTEM_CHANGEDBY_UPDATE bit
    , @MY_INT INT
    , @MY_INT_UPDATE bit
 AS  DECLARE @Ret int


RETURN @Ret
```

As you can see it's been stripped of all functionality back to its core. I had previously added a logging action and from this could see that the SP isn't being entered from the app, although is from SSMS.

Comment: Its better if you could post the code of your Stored procedure !!

Comment: For scenario 1/Silverlight, are you connecting to the same SQL server as the one in scenario 2/SSMS?

Comment: Yes, it's the same server and same database.

Comment: @Krishnraj Rana: added SQL but I don't see that as being the culprit as it's not being entered.

Comment: @Badgerspot : As you are getting the error of conversion from data type nvarchar to timestamp in your silverlight app and i have doubt on this parameter - **@APP_SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP**. I don't know how you pass parameter in code but can you pass it like this - **Convert.ToDateTime(APP_SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)**.  Note: here format of date is - "yyyy-mm-dd". Just put your format and test it and let me know...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this is that the code uses a SqlParameter, the SqlDbType of which is inferred by the SqlParameter when the [SqlParameter(String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor is used.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says `When you specify an Object in the value parameter, the SqlDbType is inferred from the Microsoft .NET Framework type of the Object.`  The value is null and so `the compiler assumes that you are trying to call the SqlParameter (string, SqlDbType) constructor overload`. This is why the parm is a nvarchar and the source of the failing nvarchar to timestamp conversion.

I presume the SSMS execution of the query works through knowing that the null value of @APP_SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP is a null timestamp, not a null nvarchar. When I specified the null parm in SSMS to be a nvarchar then I got the same error as in the Silverlight application:

> declare @ts nvarchar(40) exec "SP_FOO" 
>   @Inserted='2014-05-14 15:29:59.700', @ChangedBy=N'CORP1\Badger.Spot',@ValidationInfo=NULL,@CODE=N'NuVal',
>
> @APP_SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP=@ts,
>
> @APP_SYSTEM_UPDATED='2014-05-14 15:29:59.700', @APP_SYSTEM_UPDATED_UPDATE=1, @APP_SYSTEM_CHANGEDBY=N'CORP1\Badger.Spot',@APP_SYSTEM_CHANGEDBY_UPDATE=1,@MY_INT=1900,@MY_INT_UPDATE=1

I'm now checking for a null timestamp when the SqlParameter is constructed and setting the SqlDbType explicitly if required.

Thanks all.